# When is a model high-dimensional?

Tags: machine-learning, high-dimensional

Usually a model is considered to be high-dimensional when $n \ll p$, where $n$ is the number of the observations and $p$ the number of the variables/features (e.g. Bühlmann and van de Geer, 2011). However, you can find other definitions in the literature, as in Belloni et al. (2018) [Ref](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.01888.pdf). They write:

> High-dimensional models are characterized by having a number of unknown parameters that is not vanishingly small relative to
> the sample size.

So when is a model high-dimensional? Is there a rule of thumb or some criterion, which defines that a model is high-dimensional different than $n \ll p$? I know that there is similar question on StackExchange ([Ref](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77127/what-is-a-high-dimensional-multivariate-data-set)), but this post is relatively old and the field of high-dimensional statistics/ machine learning developed in the last ten years.

Comment: "High-dimensional" is merely a qualitative characterization, whose meaning will depend on the context, the data, the contemplated models, and even the date (because it will depend on computing capabilities: in 1950, five dimensions was extremely high-dimensional).  Thus, don't expect any specific or general answer.  BTW, if you're looking for a "criterium," attend a bicycle race!

Comment: See also the Sorites paradox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From computational point of view, the criterion for high-dimensionality of a model probably tied to [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).  Obviously, this tied to computational resources as well (as mentioned in the comment by @whuber). The dimension $p$ where by "conventional resources" provides slow solution or becomes infeasible would be called "high dimensional model".

The case $n<<p$ would be called **overparametrized model** ([see](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/469448/what-exactly-makes-a-model-overparameterized)) rather than high-dimensional. In linear algebra, it would be called [Underdetermined system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system). Recall [LASSO](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231643/lasso-vs-adaptive-lasso).

From specific domain point of view: In physics/statistics, anything $p>3$ is high-dimensional for classical mechanics, where by in statistical mechanics $p$ could be 1000s for simulations to be called high-dimensional. See [degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom). In biology/genetics "high-dimensionality" may refer to simultaneous study of different factors, see [The use of high-dimensional biology](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17206980/).

Comment: Re physics: In classical mechanics, the dimension is the number of conjugate coordinates.  A system with "moderate" dimensions might consist of a few particles to a few hundred and each particle can have $3+3=6$ position+momentum coordinates.  Re computation: although your characterization is interesting and potentially useful, it seems not to distinguish "dimension" from "model complexity" or "algorithmic complexity." A model can have very few dimensions, yet be computationally difficult to fit.

Comment: @whuber Agreed. A model indeed can be low dimensional with high algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent introduction to the statistical aspects of this question is Chapter 1.1 in [this textbook](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-73792-4) (I can recommend this book more generally). In a nutshell, a model is called high-dimensional if *p* (the number of parameters in the model) is of the order of *n* (the number of observations from that model) or larger. This definition agrees with the definitions already given, but the book makes an important distinction between high-dimensional models and high-dimensional statistics:  "high-dimensional statistics specializes in models that have many parameters" and, therefore, is *not* limited to high-dimensional models. For example, the sparsity-inducing property of certain high-dimensional estimators (such as the lasso) can be useful for model selection when *p* is large—irrespective of *n.*